# Update System.Net.Http.Formatting from Version=4.0.0.0 to Version=5.2.3.0

Tags: c#, .net

**Error:**

> Error  CS1705  Assembly 'System.Web.Http' with identity 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' 
>       uses 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced 
>       assembly 'System.Net.Http.Formatting' with identity 'System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

How do I update System.Net.Http.Formatting from 4.0.0.0 to 5.2.3.0 ?

**Edit**

Tried `Update-Package –reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` but seems this packet does not contain `System.Net.Http.Formatting`

Comment: uses NuGet package: [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension/)

Comment: @GiovanniRusso , thank, but that didn't fix the problem

Comment: @SGN did you *remove* the existing reference?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I removed manually, I used Uninstall-Package, and Update-Package -reinstall

Comment: Search for `System.Net.Http.Formatting` in all files, including `csproj`. You'll find that you have left-over references, or binding redirects to 4.0.0.0

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you are right, the library wasn't remove. I deleted and reinstalled the package, now i have the correct version

Comment: @SGN Update-Package –reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client it works for me. jajhakumullah khair

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run the following PM command to fetch `System.Net.Http.Formatting` assembly.

`Install-Package System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension`

To update:

`Update-Package System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension -ProjectName MyProject -Version 5.2.3.0`

Check `packages.config` after installation, it should be listed

```
<package id="System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension" version="5.2.3.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```

Comment: `Package 'System.Net.Http.Formatting.Extension.5.2.3' already exists in project 'x'` I still have the same version

Comment: Didyou *remove* the existing reference?

Comment: did u try updating with projectname and version? this is working fine for me

Comment: <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />

Comment: is it showing correct version in your `packages.config`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to download and install ASP.Net MVC 4 [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=30683) or using `Web platform installer`

Then it will be found in below location on your computer

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC
>   4\Assemblies\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll